trying 2560x1440 resolution on ubuntu 24.04
Currently, I have a Samsung Galaxy Book 2 and I am using an Acer 27'' monitor connected to HDMI.
When trying to use 2560x1440 resolution by commands
cvt 2560 1440 60
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 -hsync +
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00

I get the error
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
 Major opcode of failed request: 139 (RANDR)
 Minor opcode of failed request: 21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
 Value in failed request: 0x0
 Serial number of failed requests: 22
 Current serial number in output stream: 22

Does anyone know how to help?
I thank!
